# How to change frida server port in android?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, frida

By default, the frida-server in android, after installing, runs on port 27042 (127.0.0.1:27042). How can I change this port number to something else like 567 (127.0.0.1:567)? Is there any way?

Comment: Did you try to [open a new issue](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/new) for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Frida version 6.2.6, you can connect to specific IP/port like this :

```
# connect to specific IP/port
$ frida-trace -H ip:port -i "open*"
```

Sample :

```
$ frida-trace -H 192.168.1.1:1234 -i "open*"
```

Comment: The process is right, but first we need to connect to adb shell and make sure to locate to that folder.
Thank you .

Comment: what about over USB ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Set Frida-Server on Host to all interfaces and non-default port

`frida-server -l 0.0.0.0:19999 &`

#### Call Frida-Server from Host

`frida-ps -ai -H 192.168.0.38:19999`

Answer (score 0):

```
frida-server -l 127.0.0.1:567 &
```

where the interface address and port number are as you specified.

You can also use the all-interfaces IP address `0.0.0.0`

```
frida-server -l 0.0.0.0:567 &
```

and then it will listen on port 567 on all interfaces, including `127.0.0.1`