# Run frida-script on frida-server with custom port

Tags: android, routes, reverse-engineering, frida

I'm trying to bypass SSL pinning.
I used this tutorial:
https://httptoolkit.com/blog/frida-certificate-pinning/

Create frida-server and run it:

`adb shell "/data/local/tmp/sus_app -l 0.0.0.0:11124"`

And then run frida-script:

`frida -H 127.0.0.1:11124 -l agulaguglag.js -f "com.someApp.android"`

Get:

[image: output]

Also trying hosts from this question ([How to change frida server port in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731021/how-to-change-frida-server-port-in-android)).

Same result.

Which host should i use?

Comment: Do you use adb portforwarding? Because otherwise connecting to `127.0.0.1:11124` would not make any sense as `127.0.0.1` is always the local PC, not the Android device. Only if the local port 11124 would be forwarded via adb to the Android device this could work.

Comment: @Robert, yes! adb portforwarding is a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the PC side you try to connect `127.0.0.1:11124`, this means you are trying to connect to a local server port.

As frida-server is running on the Android device and not on your PC you need something that connects both sides.

The easiest way would be to forward TCP port 11124 from Android to TCP port 11124 on the PC use adb:

```
adb forward tcp:11124 tcp:11124
```